# Do you have to have iphone to make iphone apps?

Tags: iphone

Can you make iphone apps without owning an iPhone?  I have a macbook but wondered if maybe there was an emulator you could see your programs on to build your app.  All the articles I found were a couple of years old.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You CAN use JUST the emulator to develop apps and for the most part, it works the same as the actual device. Memory and some hardware items behave differently on the device, so it can be be difficult to find bugs before the app gets into the hands of your users, and performance on the device will not be as good as the simulator.

Also, things like the Camera, Location Services, Accelerometer & Gyroscope will not be usable in the simulator.

Comment: But where do I get the emulator?  What do I download to start this whole process?  just xcode?

Comment: Yep. XCode Contains the Simulator, The SDK and everything you'll need to develop locally.

Comment: looks like you have to pay though.

Comment: $5 you can get it from the MAC app store if you aren't enrolled in the  IPhone Developer program.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can (Xcode comes with a simulator) but in practice I don't think you can. Several things don't work in the simulator or work differently so you won't be able to test if your app works properly.

Answer (score 1):

The practical differences between the simulator and a real device are:

- Runs faster than the real device.
- Internet access is treated as WiFi. It doesn't emulate 3G.
- You can't tilt or control acceleration.
- You can touch with one or two (holding alt) fingets, but not more.
- It doesn't vibrate.
- Some sounds and musics don't run on the simulator.
- Accelerators, camera, gyroscope, and GPS return fixed data. Your position reported is always Cupertino, the camera is blank, and the sensors report 0.
- It can't be jailbroken.
- Keychain doesn't work.

However, that's good enough in 90% cases to develop functional applications.

Comment: Usually, it runs faster in the simulator, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, not as fast as your mac, but doesn't simulate the struggle of the real device trying to keep up when you push its limits.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly highly recommended so you can actually test on a real device. Apple provides a pretty good simulator for doing the majority of your development on, but things like testing memory usages, performance and making use of features such as a camera, location api, accelerometer, etc, you'll need the device.

Certainly, start developing using only the simulator (if you are not sure you want to do iPhone development), but I would recommend getting a device (iPod Touch is a cheaper alternative) if you decide you want to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to write. All functions of the device are not available in simulator. For example accelerometer. So if you need that then you can't work without the device. And also the simulator uses Mac environment which is far more powerful, both in terms of processing power and memory. So your app may run well on simulator, but may work poorly and even crash on device. So it's better to have a device for serious development. But obviously you can start learning on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write apps that don't suck you will need an iOS device. Period.

Doesn't matter if it's an iphone, ipod touch or ipad.
I never had an iPhone and wrote a dozen apps for it. In fact I still use my old iPod touch 2G for development.
But I wouldn't recommend that particular one for development, because now its end of life and you won't get firmware updates for it.

But last generation is totally fine.